# Torsion of finitely generated $\mathbb Z_ \ell$-module finite?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algebraic-geometry, p-adic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

Let $M$ be a finitely generated $\mathbb Z_ \ell$-module, where $\ell$ is a prime number and $\mathbb Z_\ell$ is the ring of $\ell$-adic integers. Let $T$ be its torsion submodule. Is $T$ finite?

In other words, let $f$ be a non-zero element of $\mathbb Z_ \ell$. Is the quotient module $\mathbb Z_ \ell/ (f)$ finite?

My guess is that we can assume $f= \ell^n$ for some non-negative $n$ (as units don't change the quotient). Then the quotient module $\mathbb Z_ \ell/ (f)$ should just be $\mathbb Z/(\ell^n)$. Is that correct? What triviality am I missing?

Comment: Can you be more specific? The notation $Z_l$ has more than one meaning in literature. Do you mean the localization? Do we know that $l$ is a prime?

Comment: I edited the question. I should have said that $\mathbb Z_\ell$ denotes the ring of $ell$-adic integers, and that $\ell$ is a prime number.

Comment: I don't see why the two questions are equivalent, but it seems to me that all you say about the second one is true.

Comment: The ring of $\ell$-adic integers is a principal ideal domain. So any finitely generated module can be written as a "free module" direct sum "torsion module" and the torsion part consists of finitely many copies of the form $\mathbb Z_\ell /(f)$ for some non-zero elements f.

Comment: That looks correct. Since $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$ is just the completion of $\mathbb{Z}_{(\ell)}$ at $(\ell)$, they have the same quotients by powers of $(\ell)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reasoning seems correct to me. To add more details, recall the following fact:

**Proposition:** If $R$ is Noetherian, $I$ an $R$-ideal, $M$ a f.g. $R$-module, then $\widehat{M}/I^i\widehat{M} \cong M/I^iM$, where $\widehat{}$ denotes $I$-adic completion.

Now $\mathbb{Z}_l$ is the $(l)$-adic completion of $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_{(l)}$ (the localization at $(l)$), hence is a DVR with uniformizer $l$, so as you say any nonzero $f \in \mathbb{Z}_l$ is a unit times $l^n$, and $f \mathbb{Z}_l = l^n \mathbb{Z}_l$. (To make the reduction to $\mathbb{Z}_l/f\mathbb{Z}_l$, we use the structure theorem for f.g. modules over a PID).

Comment: While I agree with your analysis, it may be worth mentioning, in the event that the OP thinks about $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$ as power series, that quotienting by $\ell^n$ is essentially just taking the power series up to the $n-1$st term, which clearly is just $\mathbb{Z}/\ell^n\mathbb{Z}$.